# Is it possible to recover data after reinstalling ubuntu on same drive

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

I just lost 2TB data when i reinstalled ubuntu 13.04 on already installed ubuntu 13.10.
Can anyone help me how to extract or recover whole partition, I am sure hard disk is formatted because its now showing only 30gb used data out of 2TB.

So is there any way to recover whole partition. I am trying test disk for now which is recovering very slowly but at least recovering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds really unlucky, are you sure it's gone? Maybe check the partitions with "disks"?
If it's really gone try this: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

From the Photorec webiste:

> PhotoRec is file data recovery software designed to recover lost files
>   including video, documents and archives from hard disks, CD-ROMs, and
>   lost pictures (thus the Photo Recovery name) from digital camera
>   memory. PhotoRec ignores the file system and goes after the underlying
>   data, so it will still work even if your media's file system has been
>   severely damaged or reformatted.

This has allowed to get deleted files back on several occasions, though I have never tried it from a formatted partition drive. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, though i am already using photorec which is already running.  Yes i am sure, its showing free space available and disk has been formatted. So may be there is any option or way to revert changes because disk is same and format is ext4.

Comment: I'm no expert in disk partitionning but as far as I know when the changes are applied to the disk there is no option to revert.
Good luck on getting your data back!