# Recover lost data

Tags: data-recovery

I have a big problem I have a laptop with dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu) , and two days ago my father made some changes to BIOS (he wanted to change Windows data from BIOS ...) and checked an option that says : `Restore Default...` and guess what I could not acces Ubuntu anymore, because my laptop load windows without asking me what system I want to load. Also my father called a fried that came to us to "repair" our laptop and he reinstalled Ubuntu. Now I'm wondering if I can still recover my data, because when I run :

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

in terminal it shows me a partition called Recovery ( I think all my lost data is there) but I don't know what to do and how to acces it.
Please help me ! I was having in Ubuntu projects and files about web development , I think now they could be lost.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/439018/is-it-possible-to-recover-data-after-reinstalling-ubuntu-on-same-drive?rq=1 which is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files

Answer (score 2):

### Avoid further damage

Do not use the drive (at least, do not mount any partitions on it), because still existing data can be overwritten.

### Have a look at

- the link to the 'original question', of which your question is a duplicate,
- the links in the comments,
- the answers at the following link, [**Accidentally did dd /dev/sda**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982552/accidentally-did-dd-dev-sda/982649#982649) and links from it.

### Try TestDisk and PhotoRec

Your computer is rebooted since overwriting, so I guess that you have to resort to [**TestDisk** and **PhotoRec**](http://cgsecurity.org).

- Try first to recover the partition table and file system(s) with TestDisk.
- Whatever file data not already overwritten can be recovered by PhotoRec, at least if not fragmented (and linux file systems are not at all as fragmented as Windows file systems).

### Backup

Many of us have had similar problems (often caused by ourselves or by sudden hardware failure), and we have learned the hard way to **make backup copies of everything, that we cannot afford to lose**.